# How to add a QWidget to a layout at runtime Using the QThread?

Tags: qt, qt5, qt4.8, qt4.6

I am using Qt5.0.1 with Visual Studio 2010 integrated,

I am rendering the video frames from the video file using ffmpeg with Qt as a QImage, actually i need to display the rendered video frame in runtime using a QThread.

I am newbie to Qt, please provide some sinppets.

Any snippets will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

im not familiar with VC++ with qt ..but 
Use [mandle brot](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/threads-mandelbrot.html) example

and fortune thread example [enter link description here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/network-blockingfortuneclient.html)

use signals to emit the video frame array or QImage.

also this code snippet

```
#include <QImage>
#include <QMutex>
#include <QQueue>
#include <QThread>
#include <QWaitCondition>

class Transaction
{
public:
    virtual ~Transaction() { }

    virtual QImage apply(const QImage &image) = 0;
    virtual QString message() = 0;
};

class FlipTransaction : public Transaction
{
public:
    FlipTransaction(Qt::Orientation orientation);

    QImage apply(const QImage &image);
    QString message();

private:
    Qt::Orientation orientation;
};

class ResizeTransaction : public Transaction
{
public:
    ResizeTransaction(const QSize &size);

    QImage apply(const QImage &image);
    QString message();

private:
    QSize size;
};

class ConvertDepthTransaction : public Transaction
{
public:
    ConvertDepthTransaction(int depth);

    QImage apply(const QImage &image);
    QString message();

private:
    int depth;
};

class TransactionThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    TransactionThread();
    ~TransactionThread();

    void addTransaction(Transaction *transact);
    void setImage(const QImage &image);
    QImage image();

signals:
    void transactionStarted(const QString &message);
    void allTransactionsDone();

protected:
    void run();

private:
    QImage currentImage;
    QQueue<Transaction *> transactions;
    QWaitCondition transactionAdded;
    QMutex mutex;
};
```

and

```
#include <QtGui>

#include "transactionthread.h"

Transaction * const EndTransaction = 0;

FlipTransaction::FlipTransaction(Qt::Orientation orientation)
{
    this->orientation = orientation;
}

QImage FlipTransaction::apply(const QImage &image)
{
    return image.mirrored(orientation == Qt::Horizontal,
                          orientation == Qt::Vertical);
}

QString FlipTransaction::message()
{
    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal) {
        return QObject::tr("Flipping image horizontally...");
    } else {
        return QObject::tr("Flipping image vertically...");
    }
}

ResizeTransaction::ResizeTransaction(const QSize &size)
{
    this->size = size;
}

QString ResizeTransaction::message()
{
    return QObject::tr("Resizing image...");
}

QImage ResizeTransaction::apply(const QImage &image)
{
    return image.scaled(size, Qt::IgnoreAspectRatio,
                        Qt::SmoothTransformation);
}

ConvertDepthTransaction::ConvertDepthTransaction(int depth)
{
    this->depth = depth;
}

QImage ConvertDepthTransaction::apply(const QImage &image)
{
    QImage::Format format;

    switch (depth) {
    case 1:
        format = QImage::Format_Mono;
        break;
    case 8:
        format = QImage::Format_Indexed8;
        break;
    case 24:
    default:
        format = QImage::Format_RGB32;
    }

    return image.convertToFormat(format);
}

QString ConvertDepthTransaction::message()
{
    return QObject::tr("Converting image depth...");
}

TransactionThread::TransactionThread()
{
    start();
}

TransactionThread::~TransactionThread()
{
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
        while (!transactions.isEmpty())
            delete transactions.dequeue();
        transactions.enqueue(EndTransaction);
        transactionAdded.wakeOne();
    }

    wait();
}

void TransactionThread::addTransaction(Transaction *transact)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    transactions.enqueue(transact);
    transactionAdded.wakeOne();
}

void TransactionThread::run()
{
    Transaction *transact = 0;
    QImage oldImage;

    forever {
        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);

            if (transactions.isEmpty())
                transactionAdded.wait(&mutex);
            transact = transactions.dequeue();
            if (transact == EndTransaction)
                break;

            oldImage = currentImage;
        }

        emit transactionStarted(transact->message());
        QImage newImage = transact->apply(oldImage);
        delete transact;

        {
            QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
            currentImage = newImage;
            if (transactions.isEmpty())
                emit allTransactionsDone();
        }
    }
}

void TransactionThread::setImage(const QImage &image)
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    currentImage = image;
}

QImage TransactionThread::image()
{
    QMutexLocker locker(&mutex);
    return currentImage;
}
```